# SharePoint Online : Powershell get id from document set created

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, content-type

I have created a document set by powershell and I would like to get ID of the document set created to update name with this ID. where Name of the document will be in format `Name_ID`

I m not able to get ID of the current document, it is empty. How to retrieve ID of the current document set?

Code I am using is:

```
#Get the content type by its name
$ct = $oList.ContentTypes | Where {$_.Name -Match "Contract"}
$Context.Load($ct)    
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

ForEach ($contract in $contractscsv){          
    $contratcName = 
    $contract.CONTRACT_NAME;
    $contratcTitle = 
    $contract.CONTRACT_NAME;

    $ContractDocumentSet = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet.DocumentSet]::Create($Context, $oList.RootFolder, $contratcName, $ct.Id)

    $Context.ExecuteQuery();

    $DocSetRelativeUrl = 
    $SiteURL+"/Contracts/"+$contratcName
    $CurrentDocSet = $Context.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($DocSetRelativeURL)
    $Context.Load($CurrentDocSet)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    $DsProperty = 
    $CurrentDocSet.ListItemAllFields

    #Update Document Set Name

    $id= $DsProperty["ID"];
    $val="$($contratcTitle)_$($id)";
    $DsProperty["FileLeafRef"] = $val;
    $DsProperty.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the associated item properties to get the ID of the object. Instead of `$Context.Load($CurrentDocSet)` use `$Context.Load($CurrentDocSet.ListItemAllFields)` . Later you should be able to access Id using `$CurrentDocSet.ListItemAllFields.Id`